# Making pynng and socket talk to each other

Tags: python, sockets, server, tcp, pynng

## TL;DR

I spin up a **server** using `pynng`, then a **client** from Python Standard Library `socket` will try to send messages to it.

The problem is that **client** can send the message, but **server** is oblivious to it.  Therefore, it doesn't work.

Am I missing something? Some low-level protocol setting? Some termination character?

The reason why I'm doing this is that I will build a Python script that uses `pynng` to act as a server.  Then a non-Python program (which I assume has knowledge of basic TCP protocols) will try to talk with this Python server.  Thus I am using the IMHO most primitive socket library I could operate, the `socket` module in the standard library.

## The details

I will present code snippets as I discuss, but I will show the full minimal code example at the end.

I am trying to spin up a server using `pynng`

```py
def server():
    with pynng.Pair0(listen=f'tcp://{HOST:s}:{PORT:d}', recv_timeout=10000) as s:
        print("Server running")
        data = s.recv()  # Blocks forever here
        print(data)
```

Then, client that looks like this will try to connect to it:

```py
def client():
    with socket.create_connection(address=(HOST, PORT), timeout=5) as s:
        print("Client connected")
        s.sendall(b'Hello world')
        print("Client sent message")
```

I put them all together in using `threading`:

```py
def main():
    srv = threading.Thread(target=server)
    cli = threading.Thread(target=client)

    srv.start()
    cli.start()

    srv.join()
    cli.join()
```

## Minimum working code

All told, this is the minimum working code:

```py
import socket
import pynng
import threading

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 65432

def main():
    srv = threading.Thread(target=server)
    cli = threading.Thread(target=client)

    srv.start()
    cli.start()

    srv.join()
    cli.join()

def server():
    with pynng.Pair0(listen=f'tcp://{HOST:s}:{PORT:d}', recv_timeout=10000) as s:
        print("Server running")
        data = s.recv()  # Blocks forever here
        print("Message received")
        print(data)

def client():
    with socket.create_connection(address=(HOST, PORT), timeout=5) as s:
        print("Client connected")
        s.sendall(b'Hello world')
        print("Client sent message")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Then I run this in the terminal

```
$ python main.py
```

It seems that the `server` is unable to `recv` messages, and the `recv` attempt thus times out at 10000ms.

```
Server running
Client connected
Client sent message
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kmonisit/miniconda3/envs/engg/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/kmonisit/miniconda3/envs/engg/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 39, in server
    data = s.recv()  # Blocks forever here
  File "/home/kmonisit/miniconda3/envs/engg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pynng/nng.py", line 454, in recv
    check_err(ret)
  File "/home/kmonisit/miniconda3/envs/engg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pynng/exceptions.py", line 201, in check_err
    raise exc(string, err)
pynng.exceptions.Timeout: Timed out
```

Comment: Don't know the `nng` and  what protocol does it speak, but quite probably it does not recognize "hello, world" as a complete and valid imput.

Comment: Yes, even a blank `s.sendall(b'')` goes over `pynng`'s head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[pynng](https://pynng.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is based on [Nanomsg Next Generation](https://github.com/nanomsg/nng), which is an implementation of the [Scalability Protocols](https://staysail.github.io/nng_presentation/nng_presentation.html).  The scalability protocols work on many different transports, including tcp, but **bare [sockets](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html) are not compatible.**  However, with a little bit of prayer and elbow grease, they can be made compatible.  Which is too say, **you can implement the scalability protocols in pure Python if need be.**

First, we need to know what the wire format is; thankfully that is documented [in an RFC in the original nanomsg repository](https://github.com/nanomsg/nanomsg/blob/master/rfc/sp-tcp-mapping-01.txt).  An implementation of a `Pair0` client is here:

```py
class Pair0:
    """A poor implementation of the Pair0 protocol"""

    def __init__(self, host, port, timeout=None):
        self._sock = socket.create_connection(address=(host, port), timeout=timeout)
        # https://github.com/nanomsg/nanomsg/blob/master/rfc/sp-tcp-mapping-01.txt
        # upon making a connection, both ends are required to send this header
        self._sock.send(b'\x00SP\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00')
        print(self._sock.recv(8))

    def send(self, data):
        # messages are simply "length + payload".  Length is 64-bit in network byte
        # order.
        packed = struct.pack('!Q', len(data))
        self._sock.sendall(packed + data)

    def recv(self):
        size_bytes = self._sock.recv(8)
        (size,) = struct.unpack('!Q', size_bytes)
        received = 0
        parts = []
        while received < size:
            data = self._sock.recv(size - received)
            received += len(data)
            parts.append(data)
        return b''.join(parts)
```

And integrated into your test program:

```py
import socket
import struct
import pynng
import threading
import time

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 65432


def main():
    srv = threading.Thread(target=server)

    srv.start()
    # sleep to give the server time to bind to the address
    time.sleep(0.1)
    _client = Pair0(HOST, PORT, 1)
    _client.send(b'hello pynng')
    _client.send(b'hope everything is going well for you')
    print(_client.recv())
    print(_client.recv())
    srv.join()


def server():
    with pynng.Pair0(listen=f'tcp://{HOST:s}:{PORT:d}', recv_timeout=1000) as s:
        print("Server running")
        for _ in range(2):
            data = s.recv()
            print("Message received")
            print(data)
        s.send(b'hello bad client')
        s.send(b'I hope you are doing okay')


class Pair0:
    """A poor implementation of the Pair0 protocol"""

    def __init__(self, host, port, timeout=None):
        self._sock = socket.create_connection(address=(host, port), timeout=timeout)
        # https://github.com/nanomsg/nanomsg/blob/master/rfc/sp-tcp-mapping-01.txt
        # upon making a connection, both ends are required to send this header
        self._sock.send(b'\x00SP\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00')
        print(self._sock.recv(8))

    def send(self, data):
        # messages are simply "length + payload".  Length is 64-bit in network byte
        # order.
        packed = struct.pack('!Q', len(data))
        self._sock.sendall(packed + data)

    def recv(self):
        size_bytes = self._sock.recv(8)
        (size,) = struct.unpack('!Q', size_bytes)
        received = 0
        parts = []
        while received < size:
            data = self._sock.recv(size - received)
            received += len(data)
            parts.append(data)
        return b''.join(parts)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now, this is nowhere near as robust as the implementation in pynng (which relies on the underlying nng implementation).  nng does The Right Thing™ in edge conditions, including losing network, handling multiple clients, keeping track of state machines, handling SIGINT, etc.  This is also an imcomplete implementation, as it does not `bind`, etc.

Disclaimer: I am the author of pynng.

Comment: As a quick takeaway, the main things I am missing are the **header**, **length + payload** messaging format, and the **`!Q`** packing format. Is that correct?

Comment: Yep!  It's not a particularly *robust* solution (compared to using `pynng` or another full implementation) but sometimes good enough is good enough...